# How to link Google Analytics account to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I have read multiple tutorials on web but I'm unable to find my tracking I'd/code on my Google Analytics property list. [This is the image which I got from web and I want to see m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p72eG.png) Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use any plugin out there. Here are some of my favorites:

1. [Google Site Kit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-site-kit/). <== This is the official Google Plugin
2. [MonsterInsights](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/)
3. [ExactMetrics](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp/)
4. [GA Google Analytics](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ga-google-analytics/) <== Simplest and just for this purpose. No unnecessary code.

Note: There are many others but these are per my favorites list and liking.

1st plugin will auto-connect with your google account and you won't need to put any ID or code into your site manually. Hence easy to set up.

Answer (score 0):

[Site Kit by Google](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-site-kit/) is great for WordPress users. By using Site Kit you don't need to manually insert the code, as depicted by the screenshot you share. The plugin can insert the code for you.

In addition to the placement of code, Site Kit can show you Analaytics and other data within your wp-admin dashboard!